# Why isn't the keyword false an integer constant expression in gcc C23?

Tags: c, gcc, language-lawyer, null-pointer, c23

Latest gcc 13.x (trunk) gives a compiler error (`gcc -std=c23`) for this code:

```
int* p = false;
```

> error: incompatible types when initializing type '`int *`' using type '`_Bool`'

How can this be correct?

---

C23 6.2.5 §8-9 (Types - the definition of integer types):

> The type `bool` and the unsigned integer types that correspond to the standard signed integer types are the *standard unsigned integer types*.
>
> The standard signed integer types and standard unsigned integer types are collectively called the *standard integer types*;

C23 6.6 §8 (Constant expressions - the definition of an integer constant expression):

> An *integer constant expression* shall have integer type...

C23 6.3.2.3 (Pointers - the definition of null pointer constant)

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, such an expression cast to type `void *`, or the predefined constant `nullptr` is called a *null pointer constant*

C23 6.5.16.1 (Simple assignment):

> **Constraints**
> /--/
>
> - the left operand is an atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer, and the right operand is a null pointer constant

Conclusion:

- `int* p = false;` is a valid form of assignment,
- because `false` is a null pointer constant,
- since it is an integer constant expression,
- since it has type `bool`, which is one of the standard integer types.

Did I misunderstand anything in the standard or is this a gcc bug? clang gives a warning but still produces an executable. I don't really see how any of the above has changed in C23 either.

Including `stdbool.h` and compiling under `gcc -std=c17 -pedantic-errors` makes it compile cleanly as expected.

Comment: "Why isn't the keyword false an integer constant expression" --> so `generic(false)` will match `bool` and not `int`?

Comment: This code has an initialization and not an assignment. But it doesn't make a difference, per 6.7.10/12 "the same type constraints and conversions as for simple
assignment apply, taking the type of the scalar to be the unqualified version of its declared type".

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, the type of `false` changes from `int` to `bool` in C23, the justification being exactly what you say. But C `bool` is still an integer type, so `false` is still an integer constant expression.

Comment: Also note that C deliberately allows an implicit conversion for the other way around: from pointer to bool (as per the rules of assignment). This is so that functions returning null on error can have their result assigned to a bool.

Comment: @user694733 Yeah there are two historical reasons causing problems. One is that C got a boolean type very late (C99) and initially that one was just a glorified integer type with `false`/`true` being constants of type `int` still. The other historical problem is that the result of logical/relational etc operators is _still_ of type `int` in C, so booleans need to be compatible with that, meaning they must remain an integer type even in C23. Whereas C++ fixed this _utter nonsense_ and made bool a proper type from scratch (in the 1980s), letting all relevant operators return a bool.

Comment: The ISO C90 committee is to blame for not sorting out this mess upon initial standardization, when backwards compatibility against various junk from the 1980s could be damned. Some 35 years later, there is an additional compatibility burden of everything developed during those 35 years, making the problem harder and harder to fix.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In addition to the paragraphs quoted in the question, there is paragraph 6.4.4.5/3:

> The keywords `false` and `true` are constants of type `bool` with a value of
> 0 for `false` and 1 for `true`.

and 6.6/7:

> An identifier that is:
> [...]
> — a predefined constant;
> [...]
> is a *named constant*

That makes `false` a named constant, which is relevant because a fuller quotation of 6.6/8 is

> An *integer constant expression* shall have integer type and shall only have operands that are
> integer constants, **named and compound literal constants of integer type** [...]

(emphasis added).

Regardless, then, of GCC implementation details surrounding the constant `false`, when taken as an expression, `false` meets C23's criteria for an integer constant expression.  Its value is specified to be 0.  It is therefore a valid null pointer constant.

**GCC's behavior here is contrary to the language spec.**

---

> I don't really see how any of the above has changed in C23 either.

None of the points you were referring to changed in C23, but what *did* change is the type of `false` and `true`.  In C17, these had type `int`.  In C23, they have type `bool` (a.k.a. `_Bool`).  As you observe, however, `bool` is an integer type, so GCC not allowing that as the type of a null pointer constant is non-conforming.

I note that GCC 8.5 does not accept `_Bool` as a valid type for a null pointer constant, either.  Given this source:

```
void *test = (_Bool)0;

int main(void) {
}
```

, it fails with the same error you observed:

> npctest.c:1:14: error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘void *’ using type ‘_Bool’

Thus, your observation appears to be a manifestation of a larger, relatively longstanding issue that is not specific to C23.

This issue is mentioned in the GCC bug tracker in comments on a related issue: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=112556.

Comment: Not sure why but the system thinks this answer is spam...

Comment: What do you mean by that, @user10186832? SO has a way to categorize posts as spam, but such posts get automatically removed.

Answer (score 14):

As it turns out, the way `false` is defined in gcc's c2x mode, it has a different type.  It's still an integer constant expression, but starting with C23 it has type `_Bool` instead of type `int`.

Passing the given line through the preprocessor in c2x mode gives the following:

```
int* p =  ((_Bool)+0u);
```

The abstract of C23 mentioned that the following was applied:

> N2393 _Bool Definitions For true and false.

And [this document](https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2393.pdf) states the following:

> 3. REFERENCE IMPLEMENTATION To add minimal support for the proposed changes, an implementation would have to add definitions that are
>    equivalent to the following lines to their startup code:
>
>    ```
>    # define false (( bool ) +0)
>    # define true (( bool ) +1)
>    ```

So the definition of `true` and `false` changes in C23.

The above causes an error in gcc going back to at least 4.9.

In contrast, the preprocessor outputs the following in c11 mode:

```
int* p = 0;
```

Which is an integer constant expression with the value 0.

Interestingly, the following compiles with a warning on all versions of gcc:

```
int x = 0;
int* p = x;
```

Output:

```
<source>:7:14: warning: initialization of 'int *' from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    7 |     int* p = x;
      |              ^
```

While the following produces the same error as above:

```
bool x = 0;
int* p = x;
```

Granted, the above is not a case of a constant expression, but it shows how gcc handles conversions from `int` to a pointer type as opposed to `_Bool`.

So given the rules on integer to pointer conversion, I would say this is a bug in gcc.

Comment: Note also paragraph 6.4.4.5/3: "The keywords `false` and `true` are constants of type `bool` with a value of 0 for `false` and 1 for `true`".  I'd cut GCC some slack on whether `false` is a *built-in* constant (which is what the standard seems to require), but it certainly must be a *constant expression*.

Comment: The `+` does not make the expression not an integer constant expression. The passage you quoted is about what operands are allowed, not about what operators are allowed, except for the sentence about cast operators.

Comment: `unsigned int` is an arithmetic type, and `(Bool_)` effects a conversion to an integer type, so the cast does not seem to be an issue for it being an integer constant expression, either.  The part about floating types says that *if* one appears, it must be an operand of a cast, not that the only casts permitted are those applied to floating-point operands.

Comment: Nice answer but I don't see how the quoted part applies "Cast operators in an integer constant expression shall only convert arithmetic types to integer types". Yeah so, the cast turns an (arithmetic type constant expression) into an integer type (which it already was from the start). So I'm not following - the key is 6.2.5 which clearly states that `bool` is an integer type.

Comment: Yes, on closer inspection it's still a constant expression.  Updates to reflect.

Comment: Regarding the update, it's debatable if `int* p = another_variable;` is a constant expression or not. Some members of the "Death Station 9000" camp that are involved in gcc maintenance claim that this is one the "implementation-defined forms of constant expressions" (and thereby breaking compatibility will all older versions of gcc).

Comment: Regardless of that, `int x = 0; int* p = x;` is not one of the valid forms of assignment so that's another case.

Comment: Note that in C23, `false` and `true` are predefined constants (not macros, except possibly as a matter of implementation detail).  `stdbool.h` has been almost entirely gutted, and in particular, the allowance for re-defining `false` and `true` has been removed.  The quoted bit from n2393 is not really relevant here, as none of that wording made it into the spec.  It should be taken as informative commentary about how existing implementations might adopt the changes, not as a normative description of the semantics of these constants.